# How do I convert a char* to an int?

Tags: c++

I need to convert a char* to an integer.  For example:

```
data.SetBytFldPos(*attribute->value());
```

The value in the attribute class is a char*.  'SetBytFldPos" takes an int.

Comment: `(int)data`. For example, `(int)"1234"` may give you `2031349120`.

Comment: Do you want the "value of the pointer" as an integer (i.e. the memory address as an integer) or do you want "what the char* points to" as an integer (i.e. the CONTENTS of the memory address)? They're two very different things.

Comment: @Bobby, if you edit the question to be more clear, we can vote you up to counter the downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lots of ways. Simplest is to use the [`strtol()` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/).

Comment: I avoid this function since it can't represent error conditions very well.  Zero is ambiguous.

Comment: @David It expresses them very well - better than the alternatives. If a conversion fails, it sets its second parameter to point to the character that caused the failure. If a range error occurs, special values (not zero) are returned. This is all described in the page I provided  alink to.

Comment: If it can't convert the number you know because the pointer still points to the start of the string.

Comment: @David: If no conversion is performed, zero is returned, and the value of `nptr` is stored in the object pointed to by `endptr`, provided that `endptr` is not a null pointer.  So it's not ambiguous.

Answer (score 8):

You don't convert `char*` to an `int`.
You may wish to parse a decimal string. This is done by `atoi()`. `atoi("1") == 1`.

Comment: Notice that `atoi("0")` and `atoi("foobar")` both return 0. To quote from the man page: The atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by nptr to int.  The behavior is the same as

           strtol(nptr, (char **) NULL, 10);

       except that atoi() does not detect errors.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to make sure that your char* represents a valid int, you can use [Boost Lexical Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm)

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

try {
    data.SetBytFldPos(boost::lexical_cast<int>(*attribute->value()));
} catch (bad_lexical_cast) {
    // something is wrong
}
```

Comment: You should use global #include style, that is <boost/lexical_cast.h>. Not that it *really* matters....

Comment: Are the boost libraries not all suffixed with hpp?

Comment: This solution is horribly inefficient compared with using strtol(), if efficiency is of any concern.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write a generic "convert string-to-X template".

```
template <class T>
T parse(const std::string& s)
{
  T out;
  std::stringstream ss(s);
  ss >> out;
  return out;
}
```

Usage:

```
int x = parse<int>("123");
float y = parse<float>("3.14159");
```

Comment: 1) Already been done: Boost::lexical_cast<>() 2) That wont work as the compiler can not choose which template function to use based on the return type (it can only choose based on the types of the parameters and they are always std::string so no help there).

Answer (score 1):

There are four ways I can think of:

- [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/).  Be warned that this function returns 0 if it can't parse your string.
- [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/), a more robust version of `atoi`.  This might cause a compiler warning because you need an `int` and its return value is `long`.
- Boost library's [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).  **I like this one if you can use Boost.**
- Use a `stringstream`, as shown below.

Code sample:

```
std::string str(*attribute->value());
std::istringstream myStrm(str);
int val;

myStrm >> val;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
// needed
#include <sstream>

// source, target
char const * p = "123";
int ival;

// conversion
std::stringstream ss(p);
ss >> ival;
```

Note though that we usually talk about "strings", not char*, as long as we don't mean pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use atoi() function

```
data.SetByteFldPos(atoi(attribute->value()));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple C function called atoi which is not so good because the error handling is in best case unintuitively and easy to forget. The (C) function strtol is much better, make it a habit to prefer that one to atoi. Here is example code from the man page:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <limits.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <errno.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int base;
       char *endptr, *str;
       long val;

       if (argc < 2) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s str [base]\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       str = argv[1];
       base = (argc > 2) ? atoi(argv[2]) : 10;

       errno = 0;    /* To distinguish success/failure after call */
       val = strtol(str, &endptr, base);

       /* Check for various possible errors */

       if ((errno == ERANGE && (val == LONG_MAX || val == LONG_MIN))
               || (errno != 0 && val == 0)) {
           perror("strtol");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (endptr == str) {
           fprintf(stderr, "No digits were found\n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       /* If we got here, strtol() successfully parsed a number */

       printf("strtol() returned %ld\n", val);

       if (*endptr != '\0')        /* Not necessarily an error... */
           printf("Further characters after number: %s\n", endptr);

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

Notice the total lack of any kind of error check for the `atoi(argv[2])` conversion. Not that strtol is super simple and intuitive to check for errors either, but it is at least better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick.

```
int pow(int a, int b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    int val = 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        val *= a;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    return val;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

int cp_length(char* cp)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    int i = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    while (cp [i] != '\0')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        i++;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    return i;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

int cptoi(char* cp)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    int val = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    for (int j = cp_length(cp) - 1, i = 0; j >= 0; j--, i++)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        if (cp [i] < 0x30 || cp [i] > 0x39) // if the character is not a digit                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            continue;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            val += (cp [0] == '-' ? -(cp [i] - 0x30) * pow(10, j) : +(cp [i] - 0x30) * pow(10, j)); // accounts for negativity                                                                                                                                                                      

    // This is the thing you need.
    return val;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```