# which is preferd use istrstream or strtol/strtod for reading number from string

Tags: c++

I have to read number from string .which one is safe and preferred

1. istrstream
2. atoi/atof
3. strtol/strto

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Why use `<iostream>` instead of `<cstdio>` ?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.1)**

Increase type safety, reduce errors, allow extensibility, and provide inheritability.

printf() is arguably not broken, and scanf() is perhaps livable despite being error prone, however both are limited with respect to what C++ I/O can do. C++ I/O (using << and >>) is, relative to C (using printf() and scanf()):

- More type-safe: With `<iostream>`, the
  type of object being I/O'd is known
  statically by the compiler. In
  contrast, `<cstdio>` uses "%" fields to
  figure out the types dynamically.
- Less error prone: With `<iostream>`,
  there are no redundant "%" tokens
  that have to be consistent with the
  actual objects being I/O'd. Removing
  redundancy removes a class of errors.
- Extensible: The C++ `<iostream>`
  mechanism allows new user-defined
  types to be I/O'd without breaking
  existing code. Imagine the chaos if
  everyone was simultaneously adding
  new incompatible "%" fields to
  `printf()` and `scanf()`?!
- Inheritable:
  The C++ `<iostream>` mechanism is built
  from real classes such as
  std::ostream and std::istream. Unlike
  `<cstdio>`'s FILE*, these are real
  classes and hence inheritable. This
  means you can have other user-defined
  things that look and act like
  streams, yet that do whatever strange
  and wonderful things you want. You
  automatically get to use the zillions
  of lines of I/O code written by users
  you don't even know, and they don't
  need to know about your "extended
  stream" class.

Comment: Doesn't really address the question. He's asking specifically about string streams versus free library functions - nowhere is cstdio mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I have used all of these but don't know which is preferable.
I did however find a decent article ([here](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Converting)) on the pros and cons between the last two which is well worth a read

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not #1. strstreams are deprecated in C++ and have lots of problems in their use. You want their replacement, - the stringstream classes declared in `<sstream>`. These are the best general-purpose solution to your problem - they are type-safe and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

The functions atoi/atof/strtol
all have more or less cumbersome and non-obvious error checking involving `errno` (strtol is way much better than atoi in any case, so avoid using atoi).
See [theese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237980/how-do-i-convert-a-char-to-an-int) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840410/check-whether-user-input-is-a-valid-string-or-not-using-c) for some discussion.
I do not know C++ very well, so I cannot comment on istrstream.