# i find a problem using atoi() method in ansi c?

Tags: c

i have a string initialized by {'\0'} every time i a loop and store some chars in it ranging from 0 to 9 when i convert atoi(temp) where temp="2" it returns me 20 instead of 2 what i have to do to get the accurate values, help required.

Comment: You should post the code that you are using, else people can only randomly guess what is going wrong.

Comment: A little punctuation in a post would help tremendously too. I have trouble just comprehending where one clause starts and another ends. Do you initialize the string each time in a loop or store characters in it each time in a loop? Or both?

Comment: In order to answer the question people need to know what you're actually doing, not what you think you're doing. You say, "when i convert atoi(temp) where temp="2" it returns me 20". This isn't true. You may think it returns 20, and you may think you passed in "2", but you're wrong about at least one of them.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what your problem with getting `atoi` to work is, you should rather use `strtol`. From the libc info manual:

> -- Function: int atoi (const char *STRING)
>
> ```
>  This function is like `atol', except that it returns an `int'.
>  The `atoi' function is also considered obsolete; use `strtol'
>  instead
> ```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237980/how-do-i-convert-a-char-to-an-int/2238063#2238063) for example of how to use strtol.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

- Have you re-terminated the string, after adding your character(s)?
- Have you allocated enough memory for the whole string, including the new null terminator?

Something like this should work:

```
char buffer[2] = {'\0'}; // note "[2]" to set aside two bytes
buffer[0] = '2';
buffer[1] = '\0'; // ensure it's still terminated
printf("%d\n", atoi(buffer));
```

Comment: You don't have enough information to answer this question; additionally with `char buffer[2] = {'\0'};` **all** `buffer[x]` (0 and 1 in this case) are guaranteed to be zero. There is no need to do `buffer[1] = '\0';` so it can't be the cause of the problem.

Comment: You're right about the null termination on the first iteration, but since (as you say) we don't have the code, we don't know whether the OP is reusing the buffer, or how many characters he's putting in each time around.  Explicitly null-terminating, although sometimes overkill, is always safe.

I figured a partial answer, which may or may not help, was more use than no answer at all.  I guess you disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the problem is not atoi, should be something else. Please check pointers, debug step by step, etc.